# Responsive lightweight remote GUI connection

Tags: unix, virtualization, xserver

Currently I know several methods of connecting to a GUI remotely, or running GUI applications remotely:

1. Microsoft Terminal Services (only
   works for remote windows;
   installation);
2. VNC (it's slow);
3. XDMCP (requires a remote X server
   running, has no session persistance);
4. Local X as remote DISPLAY for
   applications (best solution, but -
   no session persistance).

We are trying to create Solaris development environments that can replace local workstations for our developers. So one of the requirements is session persistence, and/or session mobility. And another requirement is for it to be fast, and it has to run on Solaris/UNIX.

Are there any lightweight solutions for this?

Comment: Correction to 1.: [xrdp](http://xrdp.sourceforge.net/) gives you a RDP server, and [rdesktop](http://www.rdesktop.org/) is an RDP client; both for Linux and other non-Windows operating systems.  Traditionally [VNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) is used, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either NoMachine (http://www.nomachine.com/) or FreeNX (http://freenx.berlios.de/) sounds like what you want.  Fast, keeps session if your connection drops and even works over SSH so your connections are encrypted.

Comment: NX is by far the best option for tapping into a Unix/Linux desktop remotely.

Comment: Looks like nomachine has too many features, I've been exploring it for a couple of days now. Will check the freenx option - if it's the bare minimum X-proxy that I need, then it's the perfect solution.